# Unable to use a Toolbox with a input from DataInteroperability

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, data-interoperability

I preface all of this by explaining that I'm *not* a Python developer (I usually use PHP and Java) nor do I use the ArcGIS product.  I've been attempting to use Python to assist a colleague but I'll try to provide all the information I can.

Our aim is to use a Python script that utilises toolboxes to update data.  There are two sources of data for the model: one from DataInteroperability and the other files on a mapped drive.  My current code is below:

```
import arcpy

if arcpy.CheckExtension("DataInteroperability") == "Available":
   arcpy.CheckOutExtension("DataInteroperability")
   print "Checked out \"DataInteroperability\" Extension"
else:
   print "Data Interoperability license is unavailable"

arcpy.ImportToolbox("G:/data/Toolbox/ScheduledLandChargesConversion.tbx","Land")
arcpy.Land.ScheduledLandCharges("Interoperability Connections\\ScheduledConversionLandCharges.fdl\\Assets_of_Community_Value Polygon","Q:\\Shp_Files\\Land_Charges")
```

When this is run I receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Jonathan2.py", line 10, in 
>       arcpy.Land.ScheduledLandCharges("Interoperability Connections/ScheduledConversionLandCharges.fdl/Assets_of_Community_Value Polygon'","Q:\Shp_Files\Land_Charges")
>
> File "G:\data\Toolbox\ScheduledLandChargesConversion.tbx", line 25, in ScheduledLandCharges
>
> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>
> ERROR 000732: Assets_of_Community_Value Polygon: Dataset Interoperability Connections/ScheduledConversionLandCharges.fdl/Assets_of_Community_Value Polygon' does not exist or is not supported
>
> The value does not exist.
>
> ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset 'Interoperability Connections/ScheduledConversionLandCharges.fdl/Assets_of_Community_Value Polygon'' does not exist or is not supported
>
> Failed to execute (ScheduledLandCharges).

I think this is because I'm passing the model the wrong kind of input, as it's after a *feature layer*.  I've copied the text for the DataInteroperability "path" from the toolbox's Python export, so that may be what's going wrong.  The model in question (`ScheduledLandCharges`) requires the following:

```
Help on function ScheduledLandCharges:

ScheduledLandCharges(Assets_of_Community_Value_Polygon=None, Land_Charges=None)
    ScheduledLandCharges_Land(Assets_of_Community_Value_Polygon, Land_Charges)

       (null)

    INPUTS:
     Assets_of_Community_Value_Polygon (Feature Layer)
     Land_Charges (Folder)
```

Comment: Inside ArcMap, try copying your data interop connection, pasting it in c:\temp or somewhere and updating your code within the script to reference the full path. Thats in contrast to referencing the virtual path from that node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your one of the input data is incorrect. 
The connection name(fdl) files exists on disk and may need to be passed as a parameter (as path on disk) 
Default Location : 
**C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Safe Software\Interoperability\ConnectionName.fdl\LayerName**

Comment: Many thanks, this appeared to be the problem, that and mapping a drive that was shown in the FDL file.